# Equivalent definitions of Fréchet differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, definition, frechet-derivative

In their book *The Ricci Flow in Riemannian Geometry* Andrews and Hopper have an appendix on Gâteaux and Fréchet differentiability.

They define Gâteaux differentiability as follows:

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. A function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be *Gâteaux differentiable* at $x$ if there exists a bounded linear operator $T_x \in L(X,Y)$ such that for all $v \in X$,
> $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t} = T_x v.$$ The operator $T_x$ is called the *Gâteaux derivative*.

This is the definition I was presented with in class.
Fréchet differentiability, however, is defined differently than in class (In class we used the second definition mentioned in the following passage):

> If the limit (in the sense of the Gâteaux derivative) exists *uniformly* in $v$ on the unit sphere of X, we say $f$ is *Fréchet differentiable* at $x$ and $T_x$ is the *Fréchet derivative* of $f$ at $x$. Equivalently, if we set $y=tv$ then $t \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $y \rightarrow 0$. Thus $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $x$ if  for all $y$,
> $$f(x+y)-f(x)-T_x(y)=o(\|y\|).$$

**Questions**

- What does "the limit exists *uniformly* in $v$ on the unit sphere of X" mean exactly? I know what uniform convergence is in regards to a sequence of functions. However, I cannot figure out how this concept relates to the one presented here, i.e. what sequence of functions is considered here?
- How are the two presented definitions of Fréchet differentiability equivalent?

Comment: The answer to your first question is that we require $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\left(\sup\limits_{\|v\|=1}\left\|\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}-T_x(v)\right\|\right) = 0$. Whenever we talk about limits being uniform, what we mean is to take a supremum first over the "set of uniformity" (in your case the unit sphere), and then take the limit (in your case $t\to 0$).

Comment: This is analogous to what you have seen before about sequences of functions: given any set $A$ and a metric space $(X,d)$, we say a sequence of functions $\{f_n:A\to X\}$, converges uniformly to $f$ if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sup\limits_{a\in A}d(f_n(a),f(a))\right)=0$. Here, the set of uniformity is $A$, hence the supremum, and the limiting variable is $n$. Hopefully this clarifies the language.